# SQL Server 2008 Filestream: Error when creating database with filestream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

I am going through an exercise: [How to Detach and Attach a SQL Server FILESTREAM Enabled Database](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1878)

In the step **Creating a FILESTREAM Enabled Database** I execute the following code

```
Use Master
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'FileStreamDB')
DROP DATABASE FileStreamDB
GO
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE [FileStreamDB] ON PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'FileStreamDB', FILENAME = N'D:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamDB.mdf', 
SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10% )
LOG ON 
( NAME = N'FileStreamDB_log', FILENAME = N'D:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamDB_log.ldf' , 
SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [FileStreamDB] 
ADD FILEGROUP [FileStreamGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
GO
```

It all works fine until I run the last step:

```
ALTER DATABASE [FileStreamDB] 
ADD FILE (NAME = N'FileStreamDB_FSData', FILENAME = N'D:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamData')
TO FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup
GO
```

When this code is execute I am getting the following **error**:

> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 106, Line 1
>   Unable to open the physical file "D:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamData".
>   Operating system error -2147024891:
>   "0x80070005(failed to retrieve text
>   for this error. Reason: 1815)".

I run SQL Server 2008 Enterprise (Evaluation Licence) on Windows XP Professional. The filestream is configured as per [microsoft instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

What can be the cause of that error?

Comment: Have you created an empty folder first at `'D:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamData'`?

Comment: @Martin, no but if I do I am getting another error: Msg 5170, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot create file 'D:\FileStreamDB\FileStreamData' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.

Comment: I guess Joe's answer looks likely then.

Comment: @Martin - thanks, I will try Joe's suggestion then

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a question of permissions. You need to grant the SQL Server Service Account explicit permissions on `D:\FileStreamDB`.

Comment: Joe, am I suposed to create the FileStreamData folder as well before executing the sql code?

Comment: @padn: My mistake on the file path. You don't want to create that folder. It's the higher level where permissions need to be set: `D:\FileStreamDB`. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using **Windows XP**. If you are also using **Network Service** or **Local System** as SQL Server account, you could suffer from this bug:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/435855/operating-system-error-2147024891-0x80070005-access-is-denied

The easiest fix is to use another account for SQL Server. The second option is to download the XP hotfix mentioned in the link. I don't like it; the hotfix is from 2010 and doesn't look maintained and integrated into newer XP patches. At least my XP system is up-to-date regarding patches and I still had the problem.

I've just wasted three hours looking for the source of the problem before I found the link that confirms that it's a bug in Windows XP. After changing the SQL Server account now it worked at once.

Comment: Exact same error occurred on Windows 2003 server.  I changed the SQL Server service to use the Local Service account instead of one of the others.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error on MS SQL 2014. Checked ACL three times.
Problem was that I used the path for filestream folder via linked folders feature in NTFS.
With real phisical path rooted from the real HDD letter worked like a charm.

P.S. Filepathes for the other database filetypes are working correct even via the linked folders.